# Show that there is an n×n invertible matrix P such that both P−1MP and P−1NP are diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we are given $n \times n$ matrices $M, N$ such that $MN = NM$. Let $\lambda$
be an eigenvalue of $M$ and let $E_\lambda$ be the corresponding eigenspace.

(i) Suppose that $v \neq 0$ is an element of $E_\lambda$. Show that $Nv$ is also an element
of $E_\lambda$.

(ii) Suppose now also that $E_\lambda$ is $1$-dimensional. Show that $v$ is an eigenvector
of $N$.

(iii) Suppose now that $M$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Show that there is an $n\times n$
invertible matrix $P$ such that both $P^{-1}MP$ and $P^{-1}NP$ are diagonal.

I need some help on (iii), where do I start?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that

Comment: Can you prove that there is a $P$ such that $P^{-1}MP$ is diagonal, without worrying about $N$?  What have you tried?

Comment: I guess we need to use the property MN=NM but I don't know how. Simply multiplying each side of MP=PD by N and working through it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $M$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Then $M$ is diagonalizable and each eigenspace $E_{\lambda_i}$ is $1$-dimensional. Let $v_i\neq 0$ be an element of $E_{\lambda_i}$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$ and define the matrix $P = [v_1\ldots v_n]$. Then the matrix $P$ diagonalizes $M$. By parts (i) and (ii) $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $N$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$. Thus, $P$ diagonalizes $N$ as well.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks you!